# Error Starting R: can't open it on mac for the new version

Tags: r, rstudio

I just downloaded a new version of RStudio, but I cannot open it

screenshot of the problem:

[image]

I tried to reinstall RStudio and re-start my computer, but it did not work.

Comment: You should provide information about what version of the Mac operating system you are using and what version of RStudio. It appears from the picture that you are running MacOs 10 and trying to install a version of RStudio labeled as MacOs 11+.

Comment: Did you also install R? It is not included in RStudio and has to be installed separately.